# How prove this diophantine equation $x^2-y^2\equiv a\pmod p$ have only $p-1$roots

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Question:**

> let $a\neq 0$.and $p$ is prime numbers.
>
> show that the number of ordered two-tuples $(x,y)$such  this following diophantine equation
> $$x^2-y^2\equiv a\pmod p$$
> at most $p-1$

Maybe we can use Fermat’s little theorem: if $(a,p)=1$, then we have
$$a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$$
but I can't use it,Thank you

Comment: if you take p=3 and a=1, it is easy to see that (1,0) (2,0) and (0,1) are solutions, maybe the tuples are unordered

Comment: @HugoRodrigoMasKu: $(0,1)$ is not a solution in that case as $0^2-1^2\equiv 2\not\equiv a$. The troubling case is $a=1$, $p=2$, when both $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ work. And thus the last comment of my answer was spoilered:-/

Answer (score 1):

**Extended Hint:** Assume that $p>2$. Show that to any pair $a_1,a_2\in\{1,2,\ldots,p-1\}$ such that $a_1a_2\equiv a\pmod p$ there is a unique pair $(x,y)$ of residue classes such that
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}x+y\ &\equiv a_1\pmod p,\\x-y\ &\equiv a_2\pmod p.\end{aligned}\right.
$$
Because we can choose $a_1$ arbitrarily, and to a fixed $a_1$ there is a unique $a_2$ such that $a_1a_2\equiv a$, the number of pairs $(a_1,a_2)$ is exactly $p-1$.

The assumption $p>2$ is needed in proving the uniqueness of the solution $(x,y)$ of that pair of congruences. If you are familiar with tools from linear algebra (applied to the field $\Bbb{F}_p=\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$), then this is trivial because the determinant of the coefficient matrix is $-2$.

Leaving it to you to check what surprises lie ahead, when $p=2$. There are so few choices for $a$ in that case so a brute force enumeration will do it (unless you want to use the so called Freshman's dream).

Comment: Replace the use of Freshman's dream with Little Fermat, if so inclined :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple application of quadratic residue theory.

(I omit$\mod p $ for convenience' sake)

If you choose any $y$ (notice that $\pm y$ have same solution $x$), then the equation $x^2 \equiv a+y^2$ has two solutions if $\left(\frac{a+y^2}{p}\right)=1$, and there is no solution if $\left(\frac{a+y^2}{p}\right)=-1$.

And there are exactly $\frac{p-1}{2}$ residues $k\not\equiv 0\mod p$  s.t $\left(\frac{k}{p}\right)=1$.

Hence there are at most $2\times \frac{p-1}{2}=p-1$ solutions $(x,y)$ s.t $a+y^2 \not\equiv 0$.

Moreover, if there exists $y$ s.t $a+y^2\equiv 0$, then there is a quadratic residue which cannot be represented by the form $a+y^2$, because $\left\{y^2 \mod p: y\not \equiv 0\right\}$ is the whole set of quadratic residues.

Thus, in this case, there are at most $2+2\times (\frac{p-1}{2}-1)=p-1$ solutions, like above.

Comment: if $\left(\dfrac{a+y^2}{p}\right)=1$,why the equation $x^2\equiv a+y^2$ has two solution? can you explain more detail? Thank you

Comment: The same reason in the notice I wrote above, i.e, $(x,y)$ is a solution $\Rightarrow$ $(-x,y)$ is another one.

Comment: And since my proof uses quadratic residue theory, this applies only when $p$ is odd, and in $p=2$ case the statement is not true, as Jyrki Lahtonen said.

Comment: ,I have understand your methods,Thank you

Comment: I hate to say this, but I don't think your logic holds water. How did you rule out the possibility that $\left(\dfrac{a+y^2}p\right)=1$ happens for more than $(p-1)/2$ choices of $y$? I mean $(x,y)$ and $(x,-y)$ are two solutions - not one. Or, if you prefer, all four pairs $(x,y)$, $(x,-y)$, $(-x,y)$, $(-x,-y)$ are solutions if any one of them is.

Comment: Or in yet other words. You need to show that $\left(\dfrac{a+y^2}p\right)=1$ can be true for at most $(p-1)/2$ choices of $y$. And you have not done anything of the sort.

Comment: And in yet other words. Nowhere did you use the assumption that $a\neq0$. But the congruence $x^2-y^2\equiv0\pmod p$ has $2p-1>p-1$ solution. Namely $(0,0)$, $(b,b)$ for $b=1,2,\ldots,p-1$, and $(b,-b)$ for $b=1,2,\ldots,p-1$.

Comment: Wow, that's my huge mistake, and this proof is totally wrong. Thanks to your notice.

Comment: I want to delete this post, but then comments may be deleted too...

Comment: Don't worry about the comments. Nor about the error. Such things happen to all of us. Deleting and/or editing is fine.